# Pandas combine two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have following database:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'Buy':[10,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,4],'Sell':[np.nan,7,np.nan,9,np.nan,np.nan]})

Out[37]: 
    Buy  Sell
0  10.0   NaN
1   NaN   7.0
2   2.0   NaN
3   NaN   9.0
4   NaN   NaN
5   4.0   NaN
```

I want o create two more columns called `Quant` and `B/S`

for `Quant` it is working fine as follows:

df['Quant'] = df['Buy'].fillna(df['Sell']) # Fetch available value from both column and if both values are `Nan` then output is `Nan`.

Output is:

```
df
Out[39]: 
    Buy  Sell  Quant
0  10.0   NaN   10.0
1   NaN   7.0    7.0
2   2.0   NaN    2.0
3   NaN   9.0    9.0
4   NaN   NaN    NaN
5   4.0   NaN    4.0
```

But I want to create `B/S` on the basis of "from which column they have taken value while creating `Quant`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform an equality test and feed into [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['B/S'] = np.where(df['Quant'] == df['Buy'], 'B', 'S')
```

For the case where both values are null, you can use an additional step:

```
df.loc[df[['Buy', 'Sell']].isnull().all(1), 'B/S'] = np.nan
```

**Example**

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

mystr = StringIO("""Buy    Sell
10      nan
nan      8
4       nan
nan      5
nan      7
3       nan
2       nan
nan     nan""")

df = pd.read_csv(mystr, delim_whitespace=True)

df['Quant'] = df['Buy'].fillna(df['Sell'])
df['B/S'] = np.where(df['Quant'] == df['Buy'], 'B', 'S')
df.loc[df[['Buy', 'Sell']].isnull().all(1), 'B/S'] = np.nan
```

**Result**

```
print(df)

    Buy  Sell  Quant  B/S
0  10.0   NaN   10.0    B
1   NaN   8.0    8.0    S
2   4.0   NaN    4.0    B
3   NaN   5.0    5.0    S
4   NaN   7.0    7.0    S
5   3.0   NaN    3.0    B
6   2.0   NaN    2.0    B
7   NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN
```